# Add and remove wrapper of a dynamically created component

Tags: angular, wrapper

-> [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjewtd) <-

- I would like to dynamically trigger the wrapping and dewrapping of a component (stackblitz `hello`)

What is the most elegant way to dynamically create a component (target), that is wrapped by another component (wrapper) and can be "de-wrapped" dynamically?

Any ideas?, cdk portals?, ...

---

I'm trying to build something like https://formio.github.io/aurelia-formio/ .
Therefore I want *control-inputs* to be wrapped inside a *container*. That *container* has the dragging directives, the drag handle, options button etc. All stuff I don't want in my *final rendered* version.

So the idea is to build the thing like:

`<magic-formbuilder data="largeJsonData" killWrappers="myBool"></magic-formbuilder>`

So when `killWrappers` is:

- `true`: the HTML is rendered, validation added, etc. => kill all wrappers, json gets rendered to "static" HTML form.
- `false`: we are in edit mode. We can sort inputs and tweak them because the wrappers that provide this functionality exists.

Comment: @ AndreElrico,since you can remove wrapper, my understanding is that wrapper only provides some enhancement to wrappee, otherwise, removing wrapper could cause trouble. say, wrapper holding data for wrappee to consume. If that is the case, you can consider using directive.

Comment: @ABOS I have provided some more intel.